# ¿Cómo puedo unir dos dataframe que se relacionan con tres variables y desechando observaciones según indique una de las variables en R?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, dataframe

Sean los siguientes dataframes:

```
IDENTHOGAR <- c(1011,1021,1041,1051,1071,1091) # codigo del hogar del adulto seleccionado
A7_2a <- c(1,4,2,1,1,1,1,2,1) # numero asignado al adulto seleccionado para la encuesta de adultos
niv_est <- c(1,4,4,2,3,4,4,4,2) # nivel de estudios del adulto seleccionado
edad <- c(84,26,56,70,61,35,55,38,39) # edad del adulto seleccionado
df_adultos<-data.frame(IDENTHOGAR, A7_2a, niv_est, edad)
```

```
IDENTHOGAR <- c(1011,1021,1021,1021,1021,1021,1021,1041,1041) # codigo del hogar de la persona que hace la encuesta de hogares
NORDEN_A <- c(1,1,2,3,4,5,NA,1,2) # numero de orden del adulto que hace la encuesta de hogar
A7_2a <- c(1,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,2) # numero asignado al adulto seleccionado para la encuesta de adultos
m2 <- c(63,85,85,85,85,85,85,91,91) # metros cuadrados del hogar
uds_consumo<- c(1,4.3,4.3,4.3,4.3,4.3,4.3,1.7,1.7) # unidades de consumo del hogar
df_hogar<-data.frame(IDENTHOGAR, NORDEN_A, A7_2a, m2,uds_consumo)
```

Son un resumen de la base de datos de la Encuesta Nacional de Salud en España( en realidad tengo muchas más variables y observaciones=filas), la cual se divide en 2 encuestas: la de hogares que se hace a todos los miembros del hogar; y la de adultos, que se selecciona a un adulto de cada hogar para que realice dicha encuesta.

Se desean fusionar de la siguiente manera:

La variable `IDENTHOGAR` hace referencia al hogar de la familia encuestada, `A7_2a` indica cuál es el adulto seleccionado para hacer la encuesta de adultos, mientras que `NORDEN_A` indica el número del adulto que hace la encuesta del hogar.
Necesito unir ambos dataframe de tal manera que coja todas las observaciones del `df_adultos` y que seleccione el valor que toma la variable `A7_2a` de ese mismo dataframe y que incorpore los datos del `df_hogar` para el adulto seleccionado.

Por ejemplo, Para la segunda observacion de `adultos_df` vemos que el individuo 4 (`A7_2a`) es el seleccionado dentro del hogar para hacer la enuesta de adultos, así que quiero añadir las variables `m2` y `uds_consumo` al dataframe, pero que solo coja las observaciones de `df_hogar` que se corresponda con el adulto seleccionado del primer dataframe (en este caso del df_hogares que se corresponde con la observacion `NORDEN_A=4` dentro del hogar `IDENTHOGAR=1021`) .

He hecho varios intentos con el comando merge:

```
datos_def <- merge(datos_adultos,datos_hogares,by = "IDENTHOGAR",by.x="A7_2a",by.y="NORDEN_A",all.x=T)
```

pero ninguno me da el resultado que deseo, incluso en ocasiones se me cuelga el ordenador durante 15 minutos aprox. y aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Error: no se puede ubicar un vector de tamaño  4.3 Gb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te entendí mal, el merge debiera ser así:

```
datos_def <- merge(datos_adultos,
                   datos_hogares,
                   by.x = c("IDENTHOGAR", "A7_2a"),
                   by.y = c("IDENTHOGAR","NORDEN_A"),
                   all.x = TRUE)
```

O bien si ya lo usas o te animas a usar `dplyr`:

```
library("dplyr")

datos_adultos %>% 
  left_join(datos_hogares, by = c("IDENTHOGAR", "A7_2a" = "NORDEN_A")) -> datos_def
```

Comment: Con la primera solución que me propones no obtengo el resultado que deseo: La variable IDENTHOGAR toma valores que no están en ninguno de los dos dataframes y suma +1 a cada una de las observaciones de algunas variables. Si me animo a usar dplyr sí obtengo el resultado deseado.

Comment: @juanluisAndiónTápiz, dices "la variable IDENTHOGAR toma valores que no están en ninguno de los dos dataframes", esto no lo comprendo y no entiendo que la función pueda hacer eso. ¿Podrías armar un ejemplo para reproducir esto que mencionás?

Comment: Al ejecutar el merge que propones, la variable IDENTHOGAR queda así: IDENTHOGAR=(00001011,00001021,00001041,00001051,00001071,00001091...). Añade 4 ceros a cada observación y coge los valores de ambos dataframes (yo necesito que coja solo los del dataframe datos_adultos). A parte, tengo variables como CA que asigna una Comunidad Autónoma a un número que va de 0 a 19, pues en esa variable y en otras, si la observación tiene un 15, tras usar el merge aparece como 16, es decir, añade +1 a cada observación de esas variables.

Comment: @juanluisAndiónTápiz, ciertamente es un comportamiento que no parece natural del `merge`, he intentado reproducir lo que dices pero no encuentro forma de llegar a una hipótesis, obviamente con tu ejemplo me funciona adecuadamente, fíjate si puedes compartir tus datos de alguna manera para poder analizarlo.

Comment: @pmoracho, dejo los enlaces para acceder a los microdatos de la encuesta de adultos y de hogares: (https://www.mscbs.gob.es/estadEstudios/estadisticas/microdatos/EncNacSalud/Adultos_2017.zip) , (https://www.mscbs.gob.es/estadEstudios/estadisticas/microdatos/EncNacSalud/Hogar_ENSE17.zip) . También te dejo el enlace de mi repositorio por si prefieres los datos en formato .xls o .dta, el nombre de los archivos acaban en _EA (adultos) y _EH (hogares) (https://github.com/Perfydio/Proyecto-ENS) . En el archivo script.R está todo el código que he ido haciendo incluida tu segunda propuesta.

Comment: Hola @juanluisAndiónTápiz, creo que lo que esta pasando es que el `merge`  te modifica el orden original de los datos, por lo que si ves las primeras filas de `datos_def` no son las primeras filas de `datos_adultos`, prueba ordenar la salida y verificarlo luego: `datos_def <- datos_def[order(datos_def$IDENTHOGAR),]`